# Is the initial state the eigenstate of a Hamiltonian?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, hamiltonian

Solutions to the Schrödinger equation can take the form $ \psi(r,t)=\psi(r)f(t) $, where $f(t) = e^{\frac{-iEt}{\hbar}}$,
$$ H \psi(r) = E \psi(r) ,$$ where $\psi(r)$ is the eigenstate of a Hamiltonian.

If I consider the general function $\Psi(r)$, for example taking $\Psi(r)$ as a Gaussian wave packet, does $\Psi(r)$ have to be an eigenstate of a Hamiltonian?

Comment: Your question is totally unclear. What do you mean with "when i do the practice, I can set any $\psi(r)$ I like"?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: A little notation would help, instead of writing $\psi(r,t)=\psi(r) f(t)$ write as $\psi_E (r,t)=\psi_E (r)f_E (t)$, where $\psi_E(r)$ is the eigenstate of the Hamiltonian corresponding to the eigenvalue $E$. 

The function $ \psi (r) $ is made up of a sum of the eigenstates of $H$ and you can write

$$ \psi(r) = \sum_{E} \alpha_E \; \psi_E (r) $$

Eigenstates form a mutually orthogonal set of states with the result $ \int \psi_E \psi_{E'} = 0 $ if $E \ne E'$ (it gets a bit technical depending on the spectrum of $E$).

As well, you have

$$ \psi(r, t) = \sum_{E} \psi_E (r) f_E (t) $$

Comment: Voting to reopen. The question is perfectly clear, and has a straightforward answer.

Answer (score 4):

> Solutions to the Schrödinger equation can take the form
> $\psi(r,t)=\psi(r)f(t)$, where $f(t) = e^{\frac{-iEt}{\hbar}}$,
> $$ H \psi(r) = E \psi(r) ,$$
> where $\psi(r)$ is the eigenstate of a Hamiltonian.

You are right, that functions
$$\Psi(r,t)=\psi_E(r)e^{-iEt/\hbar}$$
(where $\psi_E(r)$ is an eigenstate of the Hamiltonian
for the eigenvalue $E$) are solutions of
Schrödinger's equation.

But these are not the only solutions to
Schrödinger's equation. Actually all linear combinations from the functions above, i.e. of the form
$$\Psi(r,t)=\sum_E C_E\psi_E(r)e^{-iEt/\hbar}$$
(where $C_E$ are constants, i.e. independent of time $t$)
are solutions as well.

> If I consider the general function $\Psi(r)$, for example
> taking $\Psi(r)$ as a Gaussian wave packet, does $\Psi(r)$
> have to be an eigenstate of a Hamiltonian?

The initial state (at $t=0$) can be any arbitrary function,
including for example a Gaussian wave packet.
It doesn't need to be an eigenfunction of the Hamiltonian.

You can decompose this initial wave function $\Psi_0(r)$
into a combination of eigenfunctions, like this
$$\Psi_0(r)=\sum_E C_E \psi_E(r)$$
with certain constants $C_E$. You can actually calculate
these constants from the initial wave function:
$$C_E=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \psi_E^*(r) \Psi_0(r)\ dr$$

Then the wavefunction will continue to evolve like this
$$\Psi(r,t)=\sum_E C_E\psi_E(r)e^{-iEt/\hbar}$$

Answer (score 1):

The initial state can be anything you like. You can *express it* as the superposition of eigenstates of the Hamiltonian (and the squared normalised amplitudes in this superposition will tell you the probabilities of measuring a particular energy level $E$ when the system is in this state). But the initial state does not have to be a pure eigenstate of the Hamiltonian.